# RPA UiPath tool start issue

Tags: rpa, uipath

I have Installed UiPath community edition tool in my machine yesterday and worked in it and when I try to open today I couldn't find the tool or tool icon in my machine.

I searched in google i found this answer stating use this path to start, but I couldn't find the given path too in my machine( C:\Program Files (x86)\UiPath Studio\uirobot.exe).

How to find the tool?
Please help in this issue.

Comment: find your  - Uipath folder path- \app-18.3.2\UiRobot.exe

Answer (score 2):

UiPath Studio is found in two locations depending on the installation package you initially used.

If you used the MSI package it is installed per machine by users with administration rights and can be found in:

```
%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\UiPath\Studio
```

If you use the exe package "User Mode Installation" UiPath Studio is in the local AppData directory for the user running the installer, which does not require administrator rights.

```
%localappdata%\UiPath
```

And you will find a child directory (e.g. `app-18.4.1`) based on the version you have installed.

More information can be found in their online documentation: [UiPath Studio: Setup and Configuration > About Installation](https://studio.uipath.com/docs/about-installation)

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for the studio, you can find it here - 
"%homepath%\AppData\Local\UiPath\UiPath.Studio.exe"